# scrollable div on iOS doesn't scroll but just grows forever

Tags: html, ios, iframe, scrollable

I have a simple application that has an iFrame on the main page.  In the iFrame is a scrollable div.  Events occur and are handled inside the iFrame.  The result of these events is that new lines of text are appended to the scrollable div.

Here is the code on the parent page:

```
<iframe id="loggerWinR" src="../components/readium/loggerR/EPUB/xhtml/loggerR.xhtml" >
</iframe>
```

And the CSS

```
#loggerWinR {
    position: absolute;
    top: 470px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    padding:0.0em;
}
```

This is the body of the child page hosted within the iFrame:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;">
    <div id="loggerRDiv" style="overflow:auto"></div>

    <script src="../js/loggerR.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is the JS (loggerR.js) that manages the child page:

```
function logMsg( elm, msg ) {

   elm.style.height = (window.frameElement.offsetHeight) + "px";
   var newMsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
   elm.appendChild(newMsg);
   elm.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
   elm.scrollTop = elm.scrollHeight;
}

function handleEvent(msg) {
    logMsg( loggerRDiv, "Handler: " + “ Some new stuff here");
});
```

This works perfectly on every platform I have tested (OSX, Windows, Android, etc.) EXCEPT iOS (8).  On iOS, instead of generating a normal scrollable div, the div (and presumably the container containing it), just gets longer and longer until it extends beyond the bottom of the page and presumably off into infinity.  It IS a scrollable div (I even tried the "momentum" CSS setting) and one can scroll the div with finger gestures.  But the div just grows and grows, letting the overflow be visible. Also tried overflow:scroll with same result.

Is this just some limitation/bug of iOS or am I missing something?